# Expected declaration error (while loop)

Tags: ios, swift

I am in an iOS course and came across this error while making my app:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RootsCateogry1: ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var roots1Label: UILabel!

    var rootsWeek1 = ["acro", "micro"]
    var rootsWeek1Meaning = ["Air", "Small"]
    var roots1Show = []
    var temp = rootsWeek1.count // error here
    var p = 0

    var i = 0
    while(i<temp){ // error here
        roots1Show.append(rootsWeek1temp)
        temp++
    }

    // ...
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QKys.png)

Comment: In future, please add your code in the question, not a screenshot. It helps people to find a solution!

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten to add the `viewDidLoad` function, just wrap you code (from `var rootsWeek...` to the end of the `while` clause) within it and it should work from there.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a computed property, not a compile-time constant.  You either need to override its getter or place it in your `init` or `viewDidLoad`:

```
var temp: Int {
    return rootsWeek1.count
}
```

or:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var temp = rootsWeek1.count
}
```

Your while loop must go in a function, it cannot exist at the class level.  Consider moving that to your `viewDidLoad` as well.  You are also not declaring a variable named `rootsWeek1temp` before adding it to `roots1Show`, so the compiler won't know what to append to the array if the object does not exist.